# Check specific checbox which id is matching

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
<div class="checkbox-container">
                                <div *ngFor="let color of colors" class="checkbox-item">
                                  <input type="checkbox" [value]="color.id" ng-checked [checked]="color.id" (change)="updateAccessColorTypeID(color.id,$event)" formControlName="Colors">
                                  {{ color.colorName }}
                                </div>
                              </div>



    
      if (this.cFG.controls[formControlName]) {
                  if (formControlName === "Colors") {
                    if (this.colors && this.colors.length > 0) {
                      debugger
                      this.employee.colors.forEach((color: any) => {
                        debugger
                        if (this.colors.some((c: any) => c.id === color.id)) {
                          debugger
                         
                        }
                        // color.checked=true;
    
                      });
```

I need to checked the specific checkbox which id will match and my formControlName will be same.
i am doing like this but my checkbox are not checked